# SAS: EFA via PROC FACTOR vs PROC CALIS

Tags: sas, factor-analysis

Is there any reason to conduct an exploratory factor analysis (EFA) in PROC CALIS as opposed to PROC FACTOR?

I know the factor procedure is the most common way to conduct an EFA in SAS but I'm curious why SAS would also build it into the calis procedure (and provide some examples of EFA in the calis documentation). I've also tried an EFA in PROC CALIS and the default tables are not as useful (it doesn't output eigenvalues or communality estimates) and it doesn't appear to provide the same factor loadings as PROC FACTOR (unless I am missed an option to make them equivalent).

I know PROC CALIS has a few additional extraction methods that are not available in PROC FACTOR (e.g., WLS, DWLS, and GLS), but these methods aren't commonly used. I can't think of a situation where one of these methods would be required and the methods in PROC FACTOR would not be suitable.

They also appear to have mostly the same rotation methods.

You can even do higher-order factors in PROC FACTOR if you do the different levels in different runs (inputting PROC FACTOR output into the model for the higher-order factors).

Is there anything that PROC CALIS does that PROC FACTOR doesn't do or a situation the PROC CALIS handles better when conducting an EFA?

Comment: I think this may be a better question for Cross Validated as it doesn't encompass any programming questions, more methodology.

Comment: I was thinking this was a higher level programming question. You would have to be thoroughly familiar with the procedures to answer it. I'll move it if someone seconds your opinion or I don't get any responses here.

Answer (score 0):

Well WLS for proc calis, I think, actually apply weight on variables. let's say the variables you are using are in quite different scale, that means some of them may have really large variance which will influence the estimation on covariance matrix. So the weight you put into the WLS model actually correct the large variance.